# GCP VPC networking

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, google-kubernetes-engine, google-vpc

I have a reserved internal IP address and a nodeport service in gke, both are in the same VPC but different subnets. How do i make sure that all traffic coming to the reserved IP address over a certain port is forwarded to nodeport service and all outgoing traffic over that port from nodeport service is forwarded to the reserved IP address in GCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GKE Internal load balancer solves this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).